# Obtaining blastn databases programmatically

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

In the [Nucleotide BLAST search page](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&BLAST_PROGRAMS=megaBlast&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&SHOW_DEFAULTS=on&LINK_LOC=blasthome)

is there a way to obtain programmatically the databases listed in the "Choose Search Set" box? 
Maybe in XML format? (it doesn't matter the programming language used)

Comment: FYI : http://biostar.stackexchange.com/ is another nice place to ask this kind of question related to bioinformatics

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can get this information threw the NCBI Web services.

Using **XSLT**:

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    version='1.0'
    >

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//select[@id='DATABASE']"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="select[@id='DATABASE']">
<xsl:for-each select=".//option">
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
<xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and xsltproc:

```
xsltproc --html stylesheet.xsl "http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&BLAST_PROGRAMS=megaBlast&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&SHOW_DEFAULTS=on&LINK_LOC=blasthome" 2> /dev/null
```

returns;

```
dbindex/9606/ref_contig dbindex/9606/alt_contig_HuRef dbindex/9606/rna  Human genomic plus transcript (Human G+T)
dbindex/10090/alt_contig dbindex/10090/ref_contig dbindex/10090/rna     Mouse genomic plus transcript (Mouse G+T)
nr      Nucleotide collection (nr/nt)
refseq_rna      Reference mRNA sequences (refseq_rna)
refseq_genomic  Reference genomic sequences (refseq_genomic)
chromosome      NCBI Genomes (chromosome)
est     Expressed sequence tags (est)
est_others      Non-human, non-mouse ESTs (est_others)
gss     Genomic survey sequences (gss)
htgs    High throughput genomic sequences (HTGS)
pat     Patent sequences(pat)
pdb     Protein Data Bank (pdb)
alu     Human ALU repeat elements (alu_repeats)
dbsts   Sequence tagged sites (dbsts)
wgs     Whole-genome shotgun reads (wgs)
env_nt  Environmental samples (env_nt)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely what you intend to use this for, but the complete set of databases used by NCBI are at their FTP site: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/blast/db/
If you're only interested in the database names, just look at the bit before the first . -- most of the databases are large enough to be segmented.
In order to do a good chunk of the filtering (e.g by organism), they use alias files that restrict one or more of these larger databases by GI number.

Answer (score 0):

Some FTP API is required to get these libraries programatically. However these files are rather large, even when compressed. Probably you should at least check if the version available on the download site is not the same as your already downloaded, cached version. Java FTP libraries are reviewed at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear to me. However, here is a program using BioPerl that will obtain info from any database (specified under 'db') and any search term (specified under 'term'). This will then save a file with all of NCBIs sequences related to your search term in the given database.

```
########## http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:EUtilities_Cookbook #########

#!/usr/bin/perl -w

BEGIN {push @INC,"path to BioPerl";}
use Bio::DB::EUtilities;
my $factory = Bio::DB::EUtilities->new(-eutil      => 'esearch',
                                       -email      => 'mymail@foo.bar',
                                       -db         => 'nucleotide',
                                       -term       => 'search terms here',
                                       -usehistory => 'y');

my $count = $factory->get_count;
# get history from queue
my $hist  = $factory->next_History || die 'No history data returned';
print "History returned\n";
# note db carries over from above
$factory->set_parameters(-eutil   => 'efetch',
                         -rettype => 'fasta',
                         -history => $hist);

my $retry = 0;
my ($retmax, $retstart) = (500,0);

open (my $out, '>', 'db:protein_term-VP1_AND_Parvovirus-NOT_dependovirus,patent,partial.fa') || die "Can't open file:$!";

RETRIEVE_SEQS:
while ($retstart < $count) {
    $factory->set_parameters(-retmax   => $retmax,
                             -retstart => $retstart);
    eval{
        $factory->get_Response(-cb => sub {my ($data) = @_; print $out $data} );
    };
    if ($@) {
        die "Server error: $@.  Try again later" if $retry == 5;
        print STDERR "Server error, redo #$retry\n";
        $retry++ && redo RETRIEVE_SEQS;
    }
    #say "Retrieved $retstart";
    $retstart += $retmax;
}

close $out;
```